# How to call animation twice using media query

Tags: css, media-queries, keyframe

I am attempting to do the following...

```
@keyframes gone_then_appear {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.25;
        width: 385px;
    }
    5%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 155px
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 385px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 900px) {
    #submit {
        animation: gone_then_appear 0.5s;
    }
}
```

When the user makes the screen smaller and the window reaches 900px the animation is called, this is what I want. However, I want the animation to be called again when the user increases the window back to 900px.

I tried the following but it doesn't work right...

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    #submit {
        animation: gone_then_appear 0.5s;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    #submit {
        animation: gone_then_appear 0.5s;
    }
}
```

I want the animation to be called every time the window is 900px but only using CSS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 animations

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zu0wf3og/)

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes gone_then_appear {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes gone_then_appear2 {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}


@media (max-width: 900px) {
  div {
    animation: gone_then_appear2 1.5s;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  div {
    animation: gone_then_appear 1.5s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

*Update based on comment*

This one kicks in at 900px only

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zu0wf3og/1/)

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes gone_then_appear {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 900px) {
  div {
    animation: gone_then_appear 1.5s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Im not sure this solves my problem entirely. The min-width will call the animation whenever it is greater than 900px, so when I load the page at full screen, for example, the animation will go off. I want the animation to be called only when the user is at 900px exactly.

Comment: @Bolboa Updated my answer